# Como fazer uma Animação em CSS com efeito de arrasto. Colocar blur no movimento

Tags: css, css3, css-transições, css-animations, keyframes

Estou querendo colocar um `loader` animado em CSS com `@keyframes` em uma página, mas gostaria de colocar nele um "efeito de arrasto" como se ele desse uma "embaçada" com um rastro de *blur* seguindo o elemento quando ele se movimenta...

Tipo essa imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas só consegui chegar até aqui... Alguém tem alguma dica ou sabe uma técnica de como conseguir algo similar a isso?

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #333;
}

.bola {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 75px;
  left: 175px;
  background: #999;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: bolax 2s ease-in-out infinite;
          animation: bolax 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes bolax {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-150px);
            transform: translateX(-150px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(150px);
            transform: translateX(150px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="bola">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Até onde eu sei, não é possível fazer esse efeito somente com CSS, o ideal seria usar o **canvas**. Aqui vão dois exemplos:
<p>https://codepen.io/Tyriar/pen/BfizE
<p>https://codepen.io/depy/pen/amoXGB

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A maneira mais "rápida" de adaptar seu código é acrescentando uma "sombra ao contrário".

As cores são um degradê entre a frente e o fundo:

```
27% {box-shadow:-10px 0 0 #999,-20px 0 0 #777,-30px 0 0 #666,-40px 0 0 #555,-50px 0 0 #444}
77% {box-shadow:10px 0 0 #999,20px 0 0 #777,30px 0 0 #666,40px 0 0 #555,50px 0 0 #444}
```

No caso, eu pré-calculei as cores indo de #999 a #444, mas se quiser fazer independente do fundo, troque por `RGBA( cor do objeto, transparencia )`, fazendo a transparência cada vez maior a cada sombra.

Aplicando ao seu código:

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #333;
}

.bola {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 75px;
  left: 175px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: bolax 2s ease-in-out infinite;
          animation: bolax 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes bolax {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-150px);
            transform: translateX(-150px);
  }
  27% {box-shadow:
    -10px 0 0 #999,
    -20px 0 0 #777,
    -30px 0 0 #666,
    -40px 0 0 #555,
    -50px 0 0 #444;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(150px);
            transform: translateX(150px);
    }
  77% {box-shadow:
    10px 0 0 #999,
    20px 0 0 #777,
    30px 0 0 #666,
    40px 0 0 #555,
    50px 0 0 #444;
  }  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="bola">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Totalmente excelente! Obrigado pela contribuição!

Comment: Sensacional! Muito bom o exemplo

Answer (score 12):

Você pode criar outras bolas para serem o "blur" e alterar apenas o `animation-delay` e o `opacity`.

O código abaixo é igual ao seu, apenas adicionei os elementos `.blurN` e criei as regras para estes elementos específicos.

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #333;
}

.bola {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 75px;
  left: 175px;
  background: #999;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: bolax 2s ease-in-out infinite;
          animation: bolax 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.blur1 {
  animation-delay: 20ms;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.blur2 {
  animation-delay: 40ms;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.blur3 {
  animation-delay: 60ms;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.blur4 {
  animation-delay: 80ms;
  opacity: 0.2;
}


@keyframes bolax {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-150px);
            transform: translateX(-150px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(150px);
            transform: translateX(150px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="bola"></div>
  <div class="bola blur1"></div>
  <div class="bola blur2"></div>
  <div class="bola blur3"></div>
  <div class="bola blur4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara bem interessante a técnica, visualmente é quase imperceptível que tem mais de um elemento ali, muito bom tb!

Comment: Valeu, se tu for analisar o teu GIF não existe desfoque mas sim repetições que vão diminuindo a opacidade. Aí é só jogar com os números de opacidade e delay para chegar num ponto ideial. :D